# Recursion in a lambda expression

Tags: lambda, isabelle, lambda-calculus, hol

Is it possible to write a recursive lambda expression in Isabelle/HOL? If so, how?

For example (a silly one):

```
fun thing :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "thing x = (λx. if x=0 then x else …) x"
```

so instead of … I'd like to write the λ function applied to x-1.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one case where such things are necessary: when defining a function in a proof. I have done so, but this is far from beginner friendly, because you have to derive the simp rules by hand.

The solution is to mimic what `fun` is doing internally and expressing your definition in terms of `rec_nat`:

```
fun thing :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "thing x = rec_nat 0 (λ_ x. if x=0 then x else (x-1)) x"

(*simp rules*)
lemma thing_simps[simp]:
  ‹thing 0 = 0›
  ‹thing (Suc n) = thing n - Suc 0›
  unfolding thing_def
  by simp_all
```

I cannot recommend doing that unless it is unavoidable...

Comment: My advice is not to do this. There is a primitive recursion operator for lists (`rec_list`) that you may be able to use, but especially when things become more complicated, I would not recommend doing it that way. Just define an explicit auxiliary function with `fun`/`function`/`primrec` etc. (Especially because you will probably have to prove auxiliary theorems about this auxiliary function anyway)

Comment: I agree with Manuel. It is possible to use `rec`, but rarely a good idea, especially when the pattern is complicated.